# Passing a Wordpress ShortCode attribute value to a template

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a custom post type to centrally manage lead forms, this has an accompanying short code so a lead form can be added to a page using [lead-form id="574"] - in this example, 574 is the Id of the lead form.  When this is added to a page, I use a specific template for landing pages that include lead forms.

There are the fields in the custom post type that I need to access in the template, but in order to access them, I need the Id of the lead form first.  I have included some screenshots that I hope will clarify this a little better.

Lead forms are centrally managed in a custom post type, in this example, 574 is the Id of the custom post

[image]

The code for the shordcode grabs the id using `while( have_rows('pages', $atts['id']) ): the_row();` The fields used for the custom post type are a repeater of pages, which has a repeater of questions which has a repeater of predefined choices. These fields are created using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  The shortcode is basically looping through pages/questions/answers and building a string that the shortcode returns.   When adding a short code to a page, I specify a template in the "Page Attributes" section so I can include some styles and javascript.

[image]

template-lead-form.php is the file used for the "LP Lead Form"  The string that is built in the shortcode is outputted in the_content(), however, there are two fields that I need access to that I can only get by passing in the Id to the lead form.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd search for your shortcode in `post_content` and get id from there. Regex isn't my strong side, but probably something like this:

```
preg_match('/\[load-form [^\]]*id="([0-9]*)"\]/', $post->post_content, $res);
```

After that you'd have id in $res[1].

Comment: Yes, that found it, thank you. This is my first WP project, so I feel like a noob...